# Can we mock function which is calling axios function inside without mocking axios in JEST for nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking

Please refer below code.
Server.js code which is calling an API enclosed in loadUser function and called by fullNameGen function to create full name

```
const axios = require('axios');

function loadUser(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        console.log("Load user called");
        axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2').then((response)=>{
            resolve(response);
        }).catch((err)=>{
            reject(err);
        })
    })
    
}

function fullNameGen(){
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        loadUser().then(({data:info})=>{
            console.log(info.data);
            res(info.data.first_name+" "+info.data.last_name);
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err.message);
            rej(err.message);
        })
    })
    
}

module.exports={
    fullNameGen:fullNameGen,
    loadUser:loadUser
}
```

And in server.test.js file I am trying to mock loadUser function not the axios directly.
But the test still calling axios with the API .

server.test.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const server = require('./server');

test("Check full Name generation",async()=>{
    server.loadUser=jest.fn();
    server.loadUser.mockResolvedValue={
        data:{
            data:{
            first_name:"rav",
            last_name:"shekhar"
        }}
    };
    const result = await server.fullNameGen();

    expect(result).toBe("ravi shekhar");
    expect(server.fullNameGen).toBeCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Please tell me why this test is giving error
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

```
Expected: "ravi shekhar"
Received: "Janet Weaver"

  28 |     const result = await server.fullNameGen();
  29 |
> 30 |     expect(result).toBe("ravi shekhar");
     |                    ^
  31 |     expect(server.fullNameGen).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  32 | })

  at Object.<anonymous> (server.test.js:30:20)
```

Comment: tl;dr No. `server.loadUser=jest.fn();` only change the reference of the `module.exports` object which is not the same as the reference of `function loadUser(){...}`.

Comment: So how could we use server.loadUser mock in loaduser function?